# How to make an IR proximity sensor work in daylight?

Tags: circuit-design, infrared, proximity-sensor

I am trying to make a touchless water tap using an IR proximity detector.

I used a simple circuit:

[image: proximity sensor circuit]

It works well inside room but it doesn't work in daylight. It remains active in sunlight and if I reduce its sensitivity, its range also reduces too much.

I can use many IR transmitters to overcome this problem but this makes my circuit big and less power efficient.

I need a circuit in which the IR receiver can distinguish between the infrared coming from the transmitter or from the sun so, it won't get triggered by daylight?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you try (you might need a combination):

- use an IR remote control receiver (for a start, a [TSOP](https://www.vishay.com/docs/82459/tsop48.pdf)) with an appropriately modulated source (36 kHz + 1 kHz). this will likely be the biggest win.
- put the receiver at the end of a (black) tube, so your sensor 'sees' only the (reflected) light source
- putting the source in a similar tube might give a little added benefit because it avoids reflection of the sunlight on your source

Comment: The modulated source is clearly the solution here, and would also reduce the total number of components on the board to 3: source, detector, and a mos to drive the solenoid.

Comment: The source is not a single component: at the least a modulator (a very small micro-controller, or if you want to go retro two 555's) and the IR LED. (You *could* re-purpose a existing IR remote control with one button jammed down. I am not sure that counts as one component.) The output needs a capacitor because the output of the receiver will be a 1 kHz square wave. You can't get a constant output from these receivers (for good reasons).

Answer (score 2):

A common solution to this problem is to use a chopper of some kind.

1. Turn the transmitter off
2. Read receiver voltage
3. Turn it on
4. Read receiver voltage
5. Look at the difference between the 2 readings.

This is much less susceptible to ambient light than your circuit. It's easily done with a microcontroller.

An analog version of this is to pulse the transmitter at a given frequency, say 10 kHz. Then add a 10 kHz band-pass filter to your receiver amplifier (or maybe just a high pass would be enough).

Answer (score 1):

you can actually estimate distances to a (diffuse) reflector, using one LED and two photodiodes **IF**  one of the detectors is offset by a constant distance.

This works because one detector has 1 / Range^2 photon flux,

and

the other detector has 1 / (Range + K)^2 photon flux.

If you take log of both, the dynamic signal range is much easier to work with.

Diodes in series with the photodiodes may work well for you, if you use a high-frequency drive to power through the sunlight.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to follow the background illumination level with a low-pass filter and detect any sudden changes in level.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN1z0Y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Auto-tracking trigger.*

How it works:

- The sensor section is the same.
- R2 and C1 form a low-pass filter. You probably want a time constant of a few seconds here. It has to be short enough that it can track the sun coming out from behind a cloud but slow enough that the circuit can react to human interaction.
- OA1 buffers the C1 voltage and drives the sensitivity adjustment pot.
- CMP1 compares the current value from D1 with the long-term trend from C1.

I didn't bother to work out the logic. If it's backwards you just swap the inputs on CMP1.